# How do I select/filter Pandas columns that have an empty list?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to replace every occurrence of an empty list `[]` in my script output with an empty cell value, but am struggling with identifying what object it is.

So the data output after running `.to_excel` looks like:

[image]

Now the data originally exists in JSON format and I'm normalizing it with `data_normalized = pd.json_normalize(data)`. I'm trying to filter out the empty lists occurrences right after that with `filtered = data_normalized.loc[data_normalized['focuses'] == []]` but that isn't working. I've also tried `filtered = data_normalized.loc[data_normalized['focuses'] == '[]']`

The dtype for column `focuses` is `Object` if that helps. So I'm stuck as to how to select this data.

Eventually, I want to just instead run `data_normalized.replace('[]', '')` but with the first parameter updated so that I can select the empty lists properly.

Comment: What prints when you do `print(type(data_normalized['focuses'][0]))`?

Comment: Good call, it prints `<class 'list'>`.

Comment: Ready @simplycoding, just added a possible approach!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to cast the `df` to string type with `pd.DataFrame.astype(str)`, and then do the `replace` with regex parameter as False:

```
df.astype(str).replace('[]','',regex=False)
```

---

**Example:**

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'a':[[],1,2,3]})

df.astype(str).replace('[]','',regex=False)

   a
0   
1  1
2  2
3  3
```

Comment: This works, but it's also converting truly blank cells into `None` oddly enough. Is that expected from `astype()`? I don't see that behavior mentioned in that function's documentation or for `replace()`

Comment: Could you do `print(type(trulyblankcell))` with an original blank cell? @simplycoding , with a dataframe like this  `df=pd.DataFrame({'a':[[],1,'',3]})` with blank cell, it doesn't get as None

Comment: Looks like it's actually `None` in the JSON object before I run `data_normalized = pd.json_normalize(data)` so I need to figure out how to treat those values.

Comment: Could you add a sample of the JSON, and the resulting dataframe after using  `json_normalize`? @simplycoding

Comment: I got it. Had to add the following after your `astype` line: `df.replace(['None', 'nan'], np.nan, inplace=True)`

Comment: Oh okay, glad you complete my answer and found a solution. Please, consider accepting the answer and upvoting it, I'll appreciate it :) @simplycoding

Answer (score -1):

I have really less experience with pandas but since you cannot identify the object,try converting the list obtained to a string,then compare it to '[]'

for example,try using this

```
filtered = data_normalized.loc[string(data_normalized['focuses']) == '[]']
```